# Не сбрасывается кеш Blade при изменении шаблона

Tags: laravel-8, blade

Не сбрасывается кеш Blade при изменении шаблона, сбрасывается только после команды
php artisan view:clear

Answer (score 0):

[image: настройка phpstorm]

Нужно было снять галочку, так как она блокирует метку которая отвечает за время изменения файла, а Blade по этой метке понимает нужно ли обновлять кэш файла